# Universal reddit share button

Tags: javascript, reddit

So I want to make a bookmark that lets me share any page I'm on and has that page's URL already inputted.

For example this

```
https://www.reddit.com/submit?url=http%3A%2F%2Farstechnica.com%2Fscience%2F2015%2F04%2Fsupernova-differences-could-change-our-understanding-of-dark-energy%2F&title=Supernova+differences+could+change+our+understanding+of+dark+energy
```

will send you to Reddit with the URL (and title, but I'm not concerned with that) already input.

I have used `location.href` in this bookmark

```
javascript:location.href+="&feature=mfu_in_order&list=UL"
```

while on a YouTube video to add `&feature=mfu_in_order&list=UL` to the end of the URL of the page I'm on.

I tried to add `location.href` to `https://www.reddit.com/submit?url=`, but I get a blank submit page.

I know next to nothing about JavaScript, so forgive me if this in not possible. I think this might be failing because of same origin?

If that route doesn't work, I also have a universal facebook share bookmark

`javascript:var d=document,f='http://www.facebook.com/share',l=d.location,e=encodeURIComponent,p='.php?src=bm&v=4&i=1238893127&u='+e(l.href)+'&t='+e(d.title);1;try{if (!/^(.*\.)?facebook\.[^.]*$/.test(l.host))throw(0);share_internal_bookmarklet(p)}catch(z) {a=function() {if (!window.open(f+'r'+p,'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,resizable=1,width=626,height=436'))l.href=f+p};if (/Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent))setTimeout(a,0);else{a()}}void(0)`

I tried to replace `http://www.facebook.com/share` with `https://www.reddit.com/submit?url=` but that gets me this `http://r.php?src=bm` as the URL submitted. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did you pressed F12 and checked the console for errors?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
javascript: location.href = 'https://www.reddit.com/submit?url=' + location.href
```

Comment: Please add more details and explain your answer

Comment: I'm not really sure what else to explain: use that address for the bookmarklet, and when you click it, you'll be sent to the reddit submission page with the previous page's url pre-filled.

Comment: I was reviewing [Low Quality Posts](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) and yours was one of them. Thus I commented to expand your answer.

Comment: Right... but just because the algorithm thought it might be low quality doesn't mean it necessarily is, neh?  If you have suggestions on what needs expansion, I'd be glad to incorporate them, but as I said, it seems complete to me.